# Konica Minolta 4750EN unable to print following 12.04 upgrade

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, printing

Printer used to work fine in 11.04 and 11.10 and still does from an 11.10 installed laptop on the network.  This is a fresh 12.04 install + apt-get update and upgrade as the upgrade from oneiric via dvd hung up requiring a reinstall, but that's another story :}). Printing a test page from the printer control panel or via CUPS administration appears to send the file to the printer, which then sticks with the LCD stating processing until I reboot the printer.

I've tried installing the printer driver via cups and via the unity printing control panel without success.

Comment: I have the same problem with a Konika-Minolta bizhub C203. It worked fine until 12.04 upgrade. I'm experiencing the same issues.

Comment: OP hasn't signed on in 5+ years. 12.04 is EOL. VTC as `not reproducible`.